# C# Insert Into Access Throwing Exception

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I have code that insert into Access Database.

This code usually works, but i have one table that doesn't work and i can't understand why.

This is the exception i get:

```
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

this is the CODE:

```
if (connection == null) Connect();
command = new OleDbCommand(SQL);
command.Connection = connection;

try
{
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
finally { connection.Close(); }
```

this is the SQL string:

```
Insert INTO TrackingsDateTimes (trackingDateTimeID, trackingID, dateTime, info) VALUES(1, 0, #02/05/2017 21:37:00#, '')
```

this is the table TrackingsDateTimes:

```
trackingDateTimeID Number
trackingID Number
dateTime Date/Time
info Text
```

What am i missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Dates must be on single quotes...

Comment: @Gusman In Access, that's not true. Date literals in Access can be surrounded with octothorpes (#).

Comment: For future reference, paste the query into the Access query designer and debug it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really a good idea to have a column named as a reserved keyword.

[DATETIME is reserved](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=43463b04-0a13-406c-82ee-c5e2c9989972&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643)

If you really want to use that name (I suggest to change it) then you need square brackets around that name

```
Insert INTO TrackingsDateTimes (trackingDateTimeID, trackingID, [dateTime], info) VALUES (.....)
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you should use parameterized queries instead of inserting variables inline. The other thing is that `dateTime` is a reserved word in MS Access and *may* need to be escaped with <del>backticks</del> `[ReservedWord]`.

This should give you a good start on rewriting your queries

```
// string qry = "Insert INTO TrackingsDateTimes ( trackingDateTimeID, trackingID, `dateTime`, info) VALUES(@trackingDateTimeID, #trackingID, @dateTime, @info)"
string qry = "Insert INTO TrackingsDateTimes ( trackingDateTimeID, trackingID, [dateTime], info) VALUES(@trackingDateTimeID, #trackingID, @dateTime, @info)"

if (connection == null) Connect();
command = new OleDbCommand(SQL);
command.Connection = connection;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trackingDateTimeID", (int)1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trackingID", (int)0);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTime", DateTime.Parse("2/05/2017 21:37:00");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", string.Empty);
```

Comment: While I agree on the parameters concept (albeit here the poster uses constant values) the backticks are a syntax error for access.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to insert dates that are surrounded by # instead of single quotes.

Replace with this

`Insert INTO TrackingsDateTimes (trackingDateTimeID, trackingID, dateTime, info) VALUES(1, 0, '#02/05/2017 21:37:00#', '')`

EDIT: I'm wrong, Steve is right.

Comment: This will give a _Type Mismatch error_ Access accepts constant DateTime with a # before and after the date in the format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: @Steve I didn't realize this was the requirement in Access, only ever used T-SQL

Comment: Constant datetime values? yes. This is one more reason to always use parameters